# In Emacs how can I go back to the last buffer I was editing using ELisp?

Tags: emacs

In Emacs how can I go back to the last buffer I was editing in ELisp?

Comment: Can you give a little context about what you're trying to do?  There are a bunch of different ways to do what you want but they depend on the bigger picture...

Answer (score 5):

If you changed the buffer in ELisp code, the proper way to go back to the previous buffer is to use [`save-excursion`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Excursions.html) or [`save-current-buffer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Current-Buffer.html):

```
;; do stuff in buffer1
(save-excusion
  (set-buffer "buffer2")
  ;; do stuff in buffer2
  )
;; more stuff in buffer1
```

Answer (score 1):

In Emacs you would type `Ctrl-x b` to do that, so to find the Elisp function, type `Ctrl-h k` followed by `Ctrl-x b` and you'll get:

> [...]
>   (switch-to-buffer BUFFER-OR-NAME &optional NORECORD)
>
> Make BUFFER-OR-NAME current and display it in selected window.
>   BUFFER-OR-NAME may be a buffer, a string (a buffer name), or
>   nil.  Return the buffer switched to.
>   [...]

which should do what you want ;)